# Unable to access Associative from config file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

I am using 2 different config file which I want to load in my script.
Currently I can access the variables declared in one file(file.config) but not able to access the associative array declared in another file(file1.config). How can I configure so that I can access the other file too.

*file.config & file1.config are present in the same directory as script*

**Script.sh**

```
#Base Directory
base_dir=`pwd`

Funct () {
   . $base_dir/file.config
}

Funct1 () {
   . $base_dir/file1.config
}

#Calling function to load config file(file.config)
Funct
echo $var1

#Calling function to load config file(file1.config)
Funct1
echo ${assArray1[flower]}
```

**file.config**

```
var1=val1
var2=val2
```

**file1.config**

```
declare -A assArray1
assArray1[fruit]=Mango
assArray1[flower]=Rose
```

**Output**
: val1

*Problem* : Cannot print Associative array element - echo ${assArray1[flower]}

Comment: `pwd` gives you whichever directory you are in when you run the script, not neccesarily the script directory.

Comment: Since you never cd to a different directory, you can simplify `. $base_dir/file.config` to `. file.config`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`declare` called within a function (`Funct1`) makes the respective variable local to that function. Therefore it's not accessible outside.

You can simply omit the `declare` in `file1.config` – or use `declare -g` as suggested by [dan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13919668/dan) to declare a global variable.

Comment: Or use `declare -g` (global) to be explicit.